Как вывести слайды из комплексного поля carbon fields в тэги img?
Есть код для Carbon Fields:
Container::make( 'theme_options', 'Настройки Сайта' )
    ->add_fields(array(

        Field::make("separator", "slider_sep", "Настроки слайдера"),

        Field::make( 'complex', 'slider', 'Настройка слайдов' )
            ->add_fields( array(
                Field::make("image", "slide_photo", "Фото на слайде"),
             )
            )
            ->set_layout("tabbed-horizontal")
            ->set_min(3)
    ));

И код в index.php
        <div class="slider-main">

            <?php $table = carbon_get_theme_option('slider'); ?>

            <?php foreach ( $table as $photo): ?> 
                <img src="<?php echo $photo['slide_photo']; ?>">
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

Мне нужно вывести фотографии из Carbon Fields в поля img, т.к. сам слайдер на js принимает массив img из класса "slider-main", как ни пробовал не вышло

Нужно было просто передавать url картинки и выводить ее при помощи echo wp_get_attachment_image_url()

<div class="slider-main">
  <?php 
        $table = carbon_get_theme_option('slider');
        foreach ( $table as $photo):

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $photo['footer_rating_left_item_img'] );

        endforeach; 
    ?>
</div>

